# ERROR: ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I am having an error. I can't tell what is it causing this error in `mongodb`

**The error is the following :**

```bash
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 60df55dea691a919b4deca21
```

**The code that is making the error is :**

```
const serverModel = require('../../models/serverSchema');
module.exports = {
    name: 'hangup',
    description: 'hangup on someone if they like eating cereal with a fork!',
    category: 'fun',
    aliases: global.aliases.fun.hangup,
    cooldown: 5,
    // Umm code i guess
    async execute(message, args, client, serverData) {
        if (serverData.calling == 'connected') {
            console.log('die');
            const OtherPerson = await serverModel.findOne({ talkingWith: serverData.serverID });
            if (OtherPerson) {
                OtherPerson.talkingWith = null;
                OtherPerson.lastMsg = null;
                OtherPerson.calling = 'hangup';
                OtherPerson.save();
            }

        }
        serverData.calling = 'no';
        serverData.channel = '';
        serverData.lastMsg = '';
        serverData.talkingWith = '';
        serverData.save(); //The error brings me here
        message.channel.send(':bangbang:**__Hangingup__ bye bye**:bangbang:');
    },
};
```

I can't tell what is causing the error. I am pretty sure the error is not from any other scripts

This is what the database currently looks like for
**serverData :**

```
talkingWith: '860785717882126356'; // Id of a discord server
channel: '856912495737307137'; // Id of a discord channel
calling: 'connected';
lastMsg: null;
```

I am not gonna add how `OtherPerson` database is structured because its unknown but it looks really similar `ServerData`

Comment: This is because you are rapidly saving it. I think there is a rate limit for the mongodb API

Comment: @MrMythical Yes that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The problem was that the code was running the command `serverData.save()` too many times in a row.

To fix the problem i added an if statement which checked if the data was already saved.